Stirling's formula proof, but simpler
This is actually a homework that I am solving, and professor gave me the given formula to show Stirling's formula:
$$
\lim_{n \to ∞} \sqrt{n}\int^∞_0e^{-n(x-\log x - 1)}dx = \sqrt{2\pi}
$$
And use this fact to derive Stirling's formula:
$$
n! = \sqrt{2π}n^{n + \frac{1}{2}}e^{-n}
$$
So I am trying to solve the following:
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\int^∞_0x^ne^{-x}dx}{\sqrt{n}e^{-n}n^n\sqrt{n}\int^∞_0e^{-n(z-\log z - 1)}dx}
$$
And I finally got the following:
$$
\lim_{n \to ∞} \frac{n!}{\sqrt{2π}n^{n + 1/2}e^{-n}}
$$
However I'm not sure why this converges to 1 even though the degree of those fraction differs. The denominator's degree is $n + 1/2$ whereas the numerator's degree is $n$. I'm sure this is a pretty elementary question, but I'm really curious and having this problem for days :(
Thanks for everyone who helps me.

$\int_0^\infty e^{-n(x-\log x-1)}dx=\int_0^\infty e^{-nx}e^{n\log x}e^{n}dx=e^{n}\int_0^\infty x^n e^{-nx}dx=e^{n}\int_0^\infty \left(\frac yn\right)^n e^{-y}\frac{dy}n=\frac{n^{-n}e^{n}}n\int_0^\infty y^n e^{-y}dy=\frac{n^{-n}e^{n} n!}n$ so
$$
\sqrt{n}\int_0^\infty e^{-n(x-\log x-1)}dx=\frac{n^{-n}e^{n} n!}{\sqrt n}
$$
from which (with the fact that the expression above converges to $\sqrt{2\pi}$) the Stirling's formula follows.
